# DVWP - Across Multiple Lists with Distinct Permissions

Tags: security, data-view-web-part

I'm attempting to create a DVWP that merges 4 lists that share a content type schema but have distinct permissions. The issue I am having is that if a user does not have permissions to one of the lists the DVWP errors out with `Unable to open the specified list.`

How would I be able to create such a web part that would allow me to merge these lists showing the user items from only the lists she has access to see?

Edit: To be clear I am not doing a `JOIN` like you would in SQL. Each item from each list represents a distinct row in the view. The operation I am performing is more like a `UNION` of tables that share a schema. So if each of the 4 lists had only one item the DVWP would display 4 different rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a view with data from multiple lists as a "union" it would be more appropiate to use the [ContentByQueryWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here they discussed the same issue with permission on lists

http://sympmarc.com/2009/07/24/the-right-way-to-join-two-lists-in-a-dvwp/

as well here sample example to join lists.

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-10-performing_joins_between_sharepoint_lists.aspx

Hope these helps!

Comment: I had previously Googled and seen what you posted. The problem is no answer is given to the issue and what they are doing in these examples is not what I am doing. I will edit my question to explain better.